# Value based Foreign Key in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a 'MasterDetail' table containing columns Id, key, ItemName. I keep all enum values used in my application in this single table. e.g.

1. Closed, StatusEnum
2. In Progress, StatusEnum
3. ScreenA, ScreenEnum
4. Hold, StatusEnum

I have another table say 'Order' with one of the column as **Status** that reference this table for StatusEnum values. I want this table  'Order' to  reference only values 1,2,4 from 'MasterDetail' table but not value 3 since that is ScreenEnum value.

I am using SQL server 2016. Any thoughts please.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon for the improved formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use a generated column to keep the item type information:

```
create table MasterDetail (
    Id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    Key varchar(255) unique,
    ItemName varchar(255),
    constraint unq_masterdetail_key_ItemName unique (key, ItemName)
);

create table orders (
    OrderId int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    Key varchar(255),
    . . .
    StatusEnum as ('StatusEnum') persisted,
    constraint foreign key fk_orders_key_statusenum (key, statusenum) references masterdetail(key, itemname)
);
```

Note that the unique constraint in `MasterDetail` is redundant.  But, it allows a foreign key relationship to refer to the `key`/`itemname` pair.  That is what is needed to get types 1, 2, 4, but not 3.

Answer (score 0):

With this design, you will need the following to enforce referential integrity:

- Add ItemName column to related table(s)
- Add a composite unique constraint on MasterDetail Key and ItemName (or make that the primary key)
- Add a composite foreign key to related table(s)

Alternatively, could limit allowable values with a column level check constraint that is a subset the MasterDetail values.

I generally recommend separate tables for each "enum" if you want to enforce referential integrity. Although that will require more tables, the design is a bit cleaner, IMHO.